# Unix source code- finding my way around

Tags: c, unix

I'm quite interested in getting "stuck in" to some Unix source code, say Fedora or Ubuntu.

1. In practical terms, how would one "re-write" some part of the Unix OS. I presume you would need two machines, a dev machine and a tester? Would you need to re-install the OS on each modification of a .c file? How could I edit the file and re-compile it etc?
2. What resources are there for knowing which parts of a Unix OS/Kernel relate to which C files (I presume there is no C++) and how to find them?

Thanks in advance for help

ps my motivations for doing this are to eventually be able to learn more about the lower-level fundamentals of the Unix OS, so that I could try and get into programming high freq trading systems.

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* Unix OS anymore.

Comment: @Roman B: I was actually going to try and look at the network stack part of the kernel, not the whole OS.

Comment: @user997112 My recommendation still holds.

Comment: @RomanB, you didn't give any explanation as to why. My question is regarding the practical aspects to editing the code, not how to write C code.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad, as I don't think a reasonable sized answer could cover the amount of material that would be required to answer this question.

Comment: @David, how can it be too broad when I have asked two specific questions? One, where can I find out which C files cover which parts of the OS and two how does one edit a Unix source file ???

Comment: If you want to get into programming of high-freq trading systems, then you are looking not in that direction ! Better grab some book about high-freq trading like [this](http://www.amazon.com/All-About-High-Frequency-Trading/dp/0071743448/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1322946222&sr=1-2) or [this](http://www.amazon.com/Algorithmic-Trading-DMA-introduction-strategies/dp/0956399207/ref=pd_cp_b_1). Learn some functional programming language such as LISP/Ocaml/F#/, and implement high-freq trading algos and check them on historical finance data. Only then think about network/OS latencies...

Comment: @user997112 The answers to those specific questions are: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v3.0/linux-3.1.4.tar.bz2 and http://www.vim.org/ (or if you are of a different persuasion, http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/). I'm not sure that that's a particularly helpful answer, though.

Comment: @0x69 I said I wanted to develop high freq trading SYSTEMs, not strategies.

-David, thanks- I didnt realise I just needed to edit the file in a text editor, compile and then re-boot.

Comment: How you will implement high-freq trading system without knowing high-freq trading algorithms ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know what you're looking for. You  want to download and look at the: [linux kernel](http://www.kernel.org). Which is the same for Fedora and Ubuntu (and all other GNU Linux distributions). Second, you might want to start with something easy, like downloading the kernel, configuring and compiling it and booting it. Once you do that you can move up from there.

Comment: Hi. So lets say I get hold of the kernel source code. I could put it into a text editor, change some of the code, copy and paste (over-writing the original kernel file?) and then that's my changes to the kernel implemented?

Comment: Yes, almost. You need to compile it and boot it.

Comment: So copy, paste, over-write, compile, restart machine?

Comment: http://linuxgazette.net/111/krishnakumar.html

Answer (score 2):

I think it would probably be a good idea to have some kind of virtual machine to experiment with, that way you could do a snapshot apply your changes but still be able to go back without much effort. Also it allows you to simulate communication between PCs in a simple fashion.